# ¿Por qué la fecha es distinta en IE?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

Estoy teniendo un problema con las fechas en IE, al parecer está usando otro tipo de GMT y da como resultado una hora de diferencia lo que hace que me quede como un día de diferencia. Por ejemplo:

```js
var time = new Date(697600800000);

console.log(time);
```

Al imprimir esto en **Chrome** me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Sun Feb 09 1992 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (hora de verano de Argentina)
```

Sin embargo al hacer lo mismo en **IE 11**:

```
Sat Feb 08 1992 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora estándar de Argentina)
```

La fecha correcta es la del Chrome, es la que se guarda en la DB y devuelve después en ese timestamp.

---

La pregunta es: ¿cómo hago para saber en IE que esa fecha es de verano y en vez de hacer `GMT-0300` cambie por `GMT-0200`?

#### Lo qué ya probé:

- Usar momentjs, sigue el mismo error en IE
- Probé con otras fechas, no siempre pasa pero necesito que se arregle para estos casos.

Comment: Argentina no tiene fecha de verano.. no hay corrimientos de horas.. siempre es gmt -3 :/.. Ok, si teniamos horario de verano en ese momento...

Comment: Si, hubo fecha de verano en ciertos años. No fue siempre pero hubo.

Comment: Por eso edite mi comentario, antes de borrarlo del todo ;)

Answer (score 7):

NOTA: No he encontrado documentación al respecto, así que esto es sólo una ***conjetura***:

El horario oficial actual<sup>1</sup> de Argentina es GMT-3 no habiendo horario de verano desde 2009. Anteriormente ha habido multitud de cambios oficiales sobre si había hora de verano o no, y en qué periodos se hacia efectivo (a veces empezaba en Octubre, otras veces en Diciembre...).

Parece ser que Internet Explorer no es capaz de averiguar correctamente el horario que había en la fecha dada (en 1992) y está usando la convención actual en la que todo el año la zona horaria es GMT-3, mientras que Chrome es capaz de hacer la conversión correctamente.

Una posible solución sería usar una librería para manejar la zona horaria correctamente, como `moment.js` con la extensión `moment-timezone`:

```js
console.log(moment(697600800000).tz('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires').format())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Como curiosidad, `moment-timezone` también falla si cargamos las zonas *sólo* desde 2012:

```js
console.log(moment(697600800000).tz('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires').format())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

<sup>1</sup> A fecha de febrero de 2019

Comment: igual lo aclaro aca tambien, no en toda la argentina la zona es la misma... ni cuando la cambiaron a verano :(

Comment: No me había dado cuenta que había un data para momentjs con toda esa info, realmente me sirvió.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien comenta @PabloLozano en su respuesta, el problema parece estar en la forma en que el motor JavaScript de IE 11 calcula las fechas históricas (asumo que igual sucede con IE10, ya que usan el mismo motor). En particular las fechas anteriores al año 2007 (tampoco he encontrado documentación oficial al respecto).

El motor que usa IE, se apega a la especificación oficial [ECMA Script 5.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.8), la cual establece el procedimiento para realizar la conversión de fecha desde UTC al formato local dependiendo de la zona horaria (timeOffset) configurada en el equipo cliente.

En dicha especificación se establece lo siguiente: (Traducción propia)

> 15.9.1.8 Ajuste de tiempo en Horario de Verano. (Daylight Saving Time Adjustment)
>
> ... El algoritmo para determinar el ajuste de fecha en horario de verano (DaylightSavingTA(*t*)) medido en milisegundos, deberá depender solamente de cuatro (4) cosas:
>
> 1. El tiempo desde el inicio del año: *[t - TimeFromYear(YearFromTime(t))](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.3)*
> 2. Si el tiempo *t* cae en año bisiesto: *[InLeapYear(t)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.3)*
> 3. El primer día de la semana inicial del año: *[WeekDay(TimeFromYear(YearFromTime(t)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.3)*
> 4. La posición geográfica.
>
> La implementación ECMAScript no debería intentar determinar si la fecha exacta *"(fecha histórica)"* estuvo sujeta a horario de verano, sino solo si el horario de verano habría estado vigente si el actual algoritmo de horario de verano se hubiese aplicado en ese momento. Esto evita complicaciones tales como el tomar en cuenta los años que se usó el horario de verano durante todo el año.
>
> Si el entorno anfitrión provee la funcionalidad para determinar el horario de verano, la implementación ECMAScript tiene la libertad de asignar el comportamiento del año en cuestión, a un año equivalente (la misma diferencia con un año bisiesto y el mismo día de la semana inicial para el año) para el cual el entorno anfitrión proporciona información sobre el horario de verano.

Sabemos que el motor de IE ([Chakra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(int%C3%A9rprete_de_JScript))) usa la información de horario de verano disponible en el sistema operativo Windows. Y al parecer es dicha información la que no está completa. A diferencia de Chrome o Firefox que optan por realizar su propia implementación (¿Tal vez más completa?).

Estudiando el caso que se presenta en el contexto de esta pregunta, la fecha UTC planteada por el OP, en milisegundos *(697600800000)* corresponde al año 1992, que en este caso en particular es un año bisiesto, y en el que el primer día del año ocurre un miércoles. Durante el siglo XX, los [años bisiestos que comenzaron en día miércoles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:A%C3%B1o_bisiesto_comenzando_en_mi%C3%A9rcoles) fueron 1908, 1936, 1964 y 1992. En el siglo XXI, los años bisiestos que comienzan un miércoles incluyen 2020 y 2048.

Dado que IE se apega a la especificación ECMAScript 5.1, es muy probable (esta es una conclusión propia) que para calcular la fecha con el horario de verano usado en el año 1992, se utilice la información de horario de verano disponible para 2020 o bien para 1964. Además, dado que las fechas en IE son calculadas correctamente desde el año 2007 (al menos para Argentina, no lo he comprobado con otras zonas horarias y tampoco hay documentación oficial al respecto), asumo que el sistema operativo Windows no contiene toda la información de la zona horaria para fechas anteriores al año 2007. Además, en la Argentina, se utilizó el horario de verano hasta el 15/03/2009, cuando se establece como [horario oficial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hora_oficial_argentina) el de GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina) hasta la actualidad. Por lo tanto, y asumiendo (meras suposiciones) que no se dispone de información sobre horario de verano (para la Argentina) en Windows para fechas anteriores a 2007 y que el horario actual de la Argentina es GMT-0300, me parece que Windows toma GMT-0300 a todas las fechas anteriores a 2007.

Por otro lado, si bien se pudiera pensar que el problema está en el motor (Chakra), el cual es un intérprete JScript usado desde IE9, y siendo [Chakra Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JavaScript_engine)), la implementación de JavaScript para Microsoft Edge, que se basa en Chakra, entonces la implementación de ECMAScript debe ser idéntica, y así el error persiste en Microsoft Edge (he realizado las respectivas comprobaciones).

Por último, no quiero dejar pasar la oportunidad de aportar algo de código. Aunque bien parece que la solución dada por @PabloLozano es bastante satisfactoria, como él mismo comenta no es la única.

A veces, trabajamos en ambientes donde no es posible implementar una librería de un tercero (Moment.JS) o simplemente somos reacios a implementar una librería que no controlamos. Pueden preguntarle a [Richard Stallman](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman) qué opina del uso de librerías o frameworks que escapan a nuestro control.

Asi que, usando JavaScript en su estado puro, les dejo una solución para este caso muy particular (Hora de Argentina) para fechas a partir de 1920, ya que es a partir de ese año que Argentina se adhiere a la Convención Internacional del Huso Horario.

Esta solución requiere implementar una tabla con los valores de la diferencia horaria histórica para Argentina entre el 01/05/1920 y el 29/12/2007. Como ya lo he mencionado, las fechas anteriores al año 2007 no son correctamente calculadas por IE.

Mi prototipo de tabla es el siguiente:

```
var offsetArgentina = [{inicio: '05-01-1920', final: '12-01-1930', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'}, … , {inicio: '03-07-1993', final: '12-30-2007', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'}];
```

Para detectar el navegador usaré lo siguiente:

Para Edge: (tomado de [Detecting Microsoft Edge (Javascript)](https://github.com/4ae9b8/browserhacks/issues/167))

```
var isEdge = '-ms-scroll-limit' in document.documentElement.style && '-ms-ime-align' in document.documentElement.style && !window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;
```

Para IE 11 (tomado de: [Detección de Internet Explorer 11](http://javascriptes.com/deteccin-de-internet-explorer-11.html))

```
var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
```

Además para detectar que la zona horaria del cliente corresponde a Argentina usaré lo siguiente:

```
var time = new Date(Date.now());
var isArgentina = time.toString().indexOf('Argentina') > 0 ? true : false;
```

Lo que haré con todo esto es crear una función que me devuelva el valor correcto de la fecha según el horario de verano establecido en mi tabla (los datos fueron tomados de [Hora oficial de Argentina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hora_oficial_argentina)).

A esta función le pasamos un objeto tipo `Date` que contiene la fecha y que hemos construido usando los datos en milisegundos introducidos por el usuario.

La función devuelve un `String` con la información deseada.

Una forma de implementar es la siguiente:

```js
var offsetArgentina = [
        {inicio: '05-01-1920', final: '12-01-1930', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '12-01-1930', final: '04-01-1931', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '04-01-1931', final: '10-15-1931', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1931', final: '03-01-1932', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1932', final: '11-01-1932', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1932', final: '03-01-1933', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1933', final: '11-01-1933', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1933', final: '03-01-1934', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1934', final: '11-01-1934', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1934', final: '03-01-1935', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1935', final: '11-01-1935', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1935', final: '03-01-1936', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1936', final: '11-01-1936', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1936', final: '03-01-1937', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1937', final: '11-01-1937', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1937', final: '03-01-1938', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1938', final: '11-01-1938', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1938', final: '03-01-1939', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1939', final: '11-01-1939', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '11-01-1939', final: '03-01-1940', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1940', final: '07-01-1940', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '07-01-1940', final: '06-15-1941', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '06-15-1941', final: '10-15-1941', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1941', final: '08-01-1943', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '08-01-1943', final: '10-15-1943', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1943', final: '03-01-1946', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1946', final: '10-01-1946', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-01-1946', final: '10-01-1963', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-01-1963', final: '12-15-1963', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '12-15-1963', final: '03-01-1964', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1964', final: '10-15-1964', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1964', final: '03-01-1965', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1965', final: '10-15-1965', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1965', final: '03-01-1966', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1966', final: '10-15-1966', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1966', final: '04-02-1967', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '04-02-1967', final: '10-01-1967', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-01-1967', final: '04-07-1968', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '04-07-1968', final: '10-06-1968', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-06-1968', final: '04-06-1969', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '04-06-1969', final: '10-05-1969', diferencia: -4, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-05-1969', final: '01-23-1974', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '01-23-1974', final: '05-01-1974', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '05-01-1974', final: '12-01-1988', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '12-01-1988', final: '03-05-1989', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-05-1989', final: '10-15-1989', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-15-1989', final: '03-04-1990', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-04-1990', final: '10-21-1990', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-21-1990', final: '03-03-1991', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-04-1991', final: '10-20-1991', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-20-1991', final: '03-01-1992', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-01-1992', final: '10-18-1992', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '10-18-1992', final: '03-07-1993', diferencia: -2, hora: 'Hora de verano de Argentina'},
        {inicio: '03-07-1993', final: '12-30-2007', diferencia: -3, hora: 'Hora estándar de Argentina'}];

function calcularFecha() {
    // Detectamos navegadores
    var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
    var isEdge = '-ms-scroll-limit' in document.documentElement.style && '-ms-ime-align' in document.documentElement.style && !window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;
    //Detectamos zona horaria Argentina
    var time = new Date(Date.now());
    var isArgentina = time.toString().indexOf('Argentina') > 0 ? true : false;
    //Capturamos los milisegundos introducidos por el usuario    
    var miliseg = parseInt(document.getElementById('fechaMiliseg').value);
    //Creamos el objeto Date
    var fecha = new Date(miliseg);
    //Mostramos la fecha UTC
    var fechaUTC = document.getElementById('fechaUTC');
    fechaUTC.value = fecha.toUTCString();
    //Instaciamos los elementos HTML que se usarán para mostrar el resultado
    var lblFechaLocal = document.getElementById('labelFechaLocal');
    var lblFechaLocalIE = document.getElementById('labelFechaLocalIE');
    var lblFechaLocalCorregida = document.getElementById('labelFechaLocalCorregida');
    var txtFechaLocal = document.getElementById('fechaLocal');
    var txtFechaLocalIE = document.getElementById('fechaLocalIE');
    var txtFechaLocalCorregida = document.getElementById('fechaLocalCorregida');
    //El siguiente bloque se ejecutará segun las condiciones
    if((isIE11 || isEdge) && isArgentina) {
      console.log('Es IE11: ', isIE11, ' Es Edge: ', isEdge, ' Es Argentina: ', isArgentina);
      //Mostramos los elementos HTML
      lblFechaLocalIE.style.display = 'inline';
      lblFechaLocalCorregida.style.display = 'inline';
      txtFechaLocalIE.style.display = 'inline';
      txtFechaLocalCorregida.style.display = 'inline';
      txtFechaLocalIE.value = fecha.toString();
      // Verificamos si debemos aplicar la corrección a la fecha dada
      if(fecha < new Date('12-30-2007')) {
        console.log('Se debe corregir el offset');
        txtFechaLocalCorregida.value = stringFechaCorregida(fecha);
      } else {
        console.log('No se debe corregir');
        txtFechaLocalCorregida.value = fecha.toString();
      }
    } else {
    // se ejecuta si no es IE o EDGE y no es Argentina
      lblFechaLocal.style.display = 'inline';
      txtFechaLocal.style.display = 'inline';
      txtFechaLocal.value = fecha.toString();
    }
}
//La siguiente función recorre el array de fechas para capturar la diferencia horaria de la fecha dada
//luego llama a la función corregirOffset para construir el string
//con la fecha correcta
function stringFechaCorregida(fecha) {
    //variable que almacenará la diferencia horaria de la fecha dada
    var diferencia = 0;
    // variable para almacenar la fecha corregida
    var fechaCorregida;
    //variable para almacenar el tipo de horario
    var hora = '';
    //recorremos el array de fechas para detectar la diferencia horaria
    for (var i = 0; i < offsetArgentina.length; i++) {
      var inicio = new Date(offsetArgentina[i].inicio);
      var final = new Date(offsetArgentina[i].final);
      //nótese que el array se construyó tomando en cuenta esta comparación
      if(fecha >= inicio && fecha < final ) {
        diferencia = offsetArgentina[i].diferencia;
        hora = offsetArgentina[i].hora;
        // no necesitamos seguir iterando, salimos
        break;
      }
    }
    //verificamos que la fecha fue encontrada en nuestro arreglo
    if (!diferencia) {
      fechaCorregida = fecha;
    } else {
      fechaCorregida = corregirOffset(fecha, diferencia, hora);
    }
  //devolvemos la fecha
  return fechaCorregida;
}
// La siguiente función devuelve un String con la fecha corregida para Argentina en IE /EDGE
function corregirOffset(fecha, dif, hor) {
    //calculamos el error (deferencia entre lo devuelto por IE11 y nuestra tabla)
    var difTime = (fecha.getTimezoneOffset() + (dif * 60)) * 60 * 1000; //está en milisegundos
    //calculamos la fecha con la hora correcta
    var time = fecha.getTime() + difTime;
    //creamos un objeto Date con la fecha correcta
    var temp = new Date(time);
    //Almacenamos el string hasta la posición 27
    //(donde termina GMT)
    //Es un tamaño fijo.
    var fechaStr = temp.toString().substring(0,28);
    //Construimos el resto del string con la diferencia horaria corregida
    var gmtStr = '-0'.concat(Math.abs(dif)*100).concat(' (').concat(hor).concat(')');
    // Creamos el string final y devolvemos
    var correctedStr = fechaStr.concat(gmtStr);
    return correctedStr;
}
```

```html
<form id="dateForm" style="margin: 2rem;">
  <ul>Algunos valores que puede probar (La diferencia horaria es con respecto a Argentina):
    <li> -1194048000000  Corresponde a "Tue, 01 Mar 1932 00:00:00 GMT" (diferencia horaria histórica: -3 horas)</li>
    <li> -39052800000 Corresponde a "Sun, 06 Oct 1968 00:00:00 GMT" (diferencia horaria histórica: -4 horas)</li>
    <li> 128131200000 Corresponde a "Wed, 23 Jan 1974 00:00:00 GMT" (diferencia horaria histórica: -3 horas)</li>
    <li> 598579200000 Corresponde a "Tue, 20 Dec 1988 00:00:00 GMT" (diferencia horaria histórica: -2 horas)</li>
    <li> 605059200000 Corresponde a "Sun, 05 Mar 1989 00:00:00 GMT" (diferencia horaria histórica: -2 horas)</li>
  </ul>
  <label for="fechaMiliseg">Fecha en milisegundos:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fechaMiliseg" id="fechaMiliseg" value="697600800000">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="button" onclick="calcularFecha()">Calcular</button>
  <br>
  <label for="fechaUTC">Fecha UTC:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fechaUTC" id="fechaUTC" size="50" disabled><br>
  <label id="labelFechaLocal" for="fechaLocal" style="display: none;">Fecha Local:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fechaLocal" name="fechaLocal" size="70" style="display: none;" disabled><br>
  <label id="labelFechaLocalIE" for="fechaLocalIE" style="display: none;">Fecha Local (sin corrección IE11 / Edge):</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fechaLocalIE" name="fechaLocalIE" size="70" style="display: none;" disabled><br>
  <label id="labelFechaLocalCorregida" for="fechaLocalCorregida" style="display: none;">Fecha Local (corregida para IE11 / Edge):</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fechaLocalCorregida" name="fechaLocalCorregida" size="70" style="display: none;" disabled><br>
</form>
```

Este sería mi aporte a esta pregunta, que además de interesante plantea un posible `bug` en la forma en que bien IE11/Edge calculan la fecha para Argentina, o en la falta de datos disponibles en el sistema operativo Windows.

**P.D.**

El ambiente en el que fue probado e implementada esta solución fue Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.17134.523], usando zona horaria: (UTC -03:00) Ciudad de Buenos Aires.

Comment: Realmente es excelente la explicación que le pudiste dar a la pregunta, sabía que podía ser por algo de la versión de EcmaScript o por el mismo SO, tampoco se me planteó de como solucionarlo para este caso puntual. Es más, creo que voy a utilizar tu respuesta para solucionarlo ya que con momentjs me trae ciertos conflictos.

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras revisar la zona horaria de la siguiente manera desde la consola, ahora bien, también revisarlo desde la config de windows.

```
    var d=new Date()
    var gmtHours = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    document.write("The local time zone is: GMT " + gmtHours);
```

Lamentablemente no tengo windows para probarlo.

Comment: No me sirve saber eso porque sólo me devuelve el timezone actual, y yo necesito el timezone de cierta fecha, y al parecer depende de cada browser el timezone correspondiente.

Answer (score -3):

Lo más probable es por el motor que usan estos navegadores
IE usa Trident
Chrome usa Blink

para más info [motores de navegadores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_de_renderizado)

Ademas en [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=date) muestra que el objeto date no está totalmente implementado en IE 11

Comment: favor de revisar [answer], pues solo responder con enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: El enlace de CanIUse se refiere a si soporta `<input type="date" />` no al tipo `Date` de JavaScript.