# ¿Cómo obtengo el nombre de una zona horaria a partir de una fecha en Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

En la entrada de mi código tengo el siguiente formato de fecha: "2023-04-05T23:54:00+01:00"

A la hora de trabajar con ella ¿Cómo puedo obtener la zona horaria en nombre a partir de ese "+01:00"? En este caso las fechas pueden venir de distintos husos horarios, por lo que necesito sacar ese nombre para obtener una serie de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para un uso horario pueden existir muchos `timezone`, la función `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` devuelve todos los timezone, entonces queda recorrer esa lista, comparar el offset y luego devolver la lista resultante

```js
function GetListTimeZones(offset){
  let timezones = Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone');
  let fecha = new Date();
  let resp = [];
  for(let ts of timezones)
  {
     let ts_offset = fecha.toLocaleString("es",{timeZoneName  : "longOffset", timeZone : `${ts}`});
     if(ts_offset.includes(offset)){
      resp.push(ts);
    }
  }

  return resp;
}


let r = GetListTimeZones("-05:00");

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no puedes: estás confundiendo los husos horarios con las zonas horarias:

Hay 24 usos horarios, donde el Meridiano de Greenwich se considera el punto de referencia (00:00) y puedes sumar o restar una hora cada 15 grados.
Hay multitud de zonas horarias, que delimitan la hora local. Algunas cubren más de un huso horario y muchas veces varias zonas horarias comparten el mismo huso horario.

Es importante entender la diferencia: dos países pueden compartir la hora local durante la mayor parte del año pero uno de ellos puede aplicar el horario de verano unas semanas antes que el otro o directamente es posible que un país no realice el cambio de hora, por lo que no es lo mismo decir CET (Central European Time) que WAT (West Africa Time): ambos tienen la hora +01:00 durante el invierno pero CET es +02:00 durante el verano, lo que sería equivalente a CAT (Central Africa Time).

Aquí tienes una pregunta / respuesta que sirve de ejemplo para entender lo complicado que puede resultar averiguar la hora exacta en un lugar concreto, incluso sabiendo la zona horaria: [¿Por qué la fecha es distinta en IE?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234167/por-qu%c3%a9-la-fecha-es-distinta-en-ie/235093#235093)

Comment: Vaya. Muchas gracias, la verdad es que sí, llevo un lío interesante. ¡Gracias de nuevo!